# Post a Complex object to MVC controller using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

So I am trying to build a travel-based site where I take some values from the UI and am trying to bind it to an object, and then hit an Http post to a controller, which will then take care of the DB part of the JOB. The problem is the controller will be receiving the post data as a complex object. So my present question is actually multifold.

1. How do I construct an instance and assign values for such a complex object in my client(AngularJS)code?
2. Is there any way razor can help us by fetching the object.
3. Once I have the finished, object if I stringify the JSON will the controller be able to accept that version.

I will be giving some code for reference.

ModelClass:

```
public class SearchCriteria
    {
        public Routes Routes { get; set; }
        public int JType { get; set; }
        public PaxInfo PaxInfo { get; set; }
        public string SearchFingerPrintID { get; set; }
    }
```

in the above class Routes is a complex type that needs to be addressed.

Razor Code to import the Model Object

```
@{
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var SampleReqObj = serializer.Serialize(Model.MyRequest);
 }
```

Some Angularjs code.

```
$scope.ButtonClick = function () {

    var ReqObjFinal = JSON.parse(SampleReqObj);

    var post = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/Main/DemoFormDataSubmit",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(ReqObjFinal),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    });

    post.success(function () {
        $window.alert("Successful Call");
    });

    post.error(function () {
        $window.alert("Not working bro");
    });
}
```

Field that i want to fetch from my UI.

```
<input type="text" name="Departure" ng-click="DeptLoadList()"
       ng-model="Departure" id="Departure" ng-keydown="completeDept(Departure)"
       class="form-control" />
```

I am a beginner for angular-js so thanks in advance for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ViewModel. And use to it your view page head

```
@Model.YourViewModel
```

and use page input name ex :

```
<form action="post" action="YourController/Save">
<input name="YourViewModel.PropName" type="text" value="@YourViewModel.PropName" />
</form>
```

and you can post to controller ex:

```
 [HttpPost]
 function void Save(YourViewModel data){
    string value=data.YourProperty;
 }
```

You can create a structure;

```
public class YourViewModel{ 
  ... 
   public string DataJson{get;set;}
}
```

and

```
var pageData=Json.parse(@Model.DataJson); 
pageData.YourProp="Your value";

$http({ method: "POST", url: "/YourController/Save", dataType: 'json', data: 
pageData, .. })
```

that object goes to your controller

Comment: Actually I have already used some angular functionality with the Input field and although this basic functionality can be implemented... I want to specifically bind the ng-model field with the object property. So I want to be in a position to traverse through all the nested objects.

Comment: You can create a structure;
public class YourViewModel{
...
public string DataJson{get;set;}
}
and
var pageData=Json.parse(@Model.DataJson);

pageData.YourProp="Your value";

$http({ method: "POST",
        url: "/YourController/Save",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: pageData,
..
})
that object goes to your controller

Comment: @ÖmürBuruk, your answer uses page submit which OP does not want to use.